# Flutter: Listview inside TabBar not showing

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

**My "ListView" not showing inside "TabBar".**

drive.google.com/file/d/1MLB7oizJ468V1SmCO_IsjL6OaoGhUAPd/… ----- **List Page Code**
drive.google.com/file/d/1d-iRa14-DupdLo3QdHd_iCHFkGi-_HD6/… **TabBar Code**

**"TabBar" Section code:**
[image]

**"ListView" section code:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all the question is unclear and you should also provide code so that we can replicate the issue at our end.
Secondly, as per my understanding you are using `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in both your `TabBar()` and your `ListView()` which is hindering the ability of your ListView to scroll. It is visible as I can see in the Substitutes section but it is not scrolling is your issue I imagine.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MLB7oizJ468V1SmCO_IsjL6OaoGhUAPd/view?usp=sharing ----- List Page Code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-iRa14-DupdLo3QdHd_iCHFkGi-_HD6/view?usp=sharing---- TabBar Code

Comment: "NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()" in the TabBar used for preventing swapping

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pastebin.com to share your code. Never use such kind of drive link. This is difficult for a developer. They first need to download the code in order to debug. Also, share images to describe your issue.